# Mongoose get only the length of a field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is an example of my Mongoose schema:

```
mongoose.model('Support', {
  createdBy: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  title: String,
  replies: { type: Array, default: [] }
}
```

The replies array can contain several objects, to which I'm not interested in the first query, but I do need the length of the array.

Is there a mongoose solution for this problem? Currently I'm just looping through each document.

My code so far:

```
Support.find({}, function(err, docs) {
  if (err) throw err;

  async.each(docs, function(doc, next) {
    doc.replies = doc.replies.length;
    next();
  }, function() {
    /* Work with the result */
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`$size`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size) operator with [`aggregate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) to get the number of items in an array:

```
Support.aggregate(
    {$project: {
        createdBy: 1,
        title: 1,
        replies: {$size: '$replies'}
    }},
    function(err, docs) { ... }
);
```